# Search with previous regex in git when staging hunks

Tags: git

I have a project where, more often than not, the software we use injects hundreds of lines of unnecessary changes (it'll move everything in our OMD by a few pixels). I usually stage with `git add -p` to commit only my own changes. Today I renamed something and wanted to stage all hunks matching the new name, so I tried the `/` option and found that I can't reuse the prior regex to find each hunk without copy/pasting it.

Is there a way to search for the previous regex from the `/` when staging with `git add -p`, or do I have to copy/paste the regex every time? It's not a huge deal, but I feel like I'm either missing something or `git add -p` is simpler than I thought.

Comment: That sounds like extremely reasonable functionality.  As I recall, the initial implementation `/` in `git-add` was incredibly basic, and there was no readline support.  This sounds like a great feature to add!

Comment: Apparently so! I was going in circles for minutes before realizing the search finds hunks you've already accepted. I was wondering why my changes never seemed to end

Comment: `git add -p` is actually a Perl script (`$(git --exec-path)/git-add--interactive`), so if you're a Perl programmer, you're all set to work on it...